# How to send response to client from php websocket without getting request from client?

Tags: php, html, websocket

Hi i am new to websocket connection. I am using [This Example](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets) to create a client server connection using Websockets class. Here we can send request to server and receive a response.

But i want to receive response from server without sending request. e.g., server checks in database and if any new record or change in status is found than it will notify client with a response.

I know about [HTML5 SSE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) and i have also worked with it. I want similar functionality in websockets, that is it should send a response to client whenever something new in data found.

How to get that response without sending a request using php websockets

Comment: As a user with 413 reputation, you should know quite good what happens with questions of this type...

Comment: @Twinfriends Well i am stucked in this problem from last 8 hours. and did not find any proper solution or may be i haven't understood php websocket completly that is why i am asking this question.

Comment: I haven't look in your specific base-project, but it can be done after user first-opening the socket with server. You should save the user, then initiate a message to them. If you wish, i can share code based on some another API.